# how do i get user details based on the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

can someone please help me with some code, I have two arrays one with product Id and the other with full product details.I want to console log the products based on the product id array, so the product id array will search the product details array. If it finds a match it will print out the whole product details. Here are the two arrays:

```
var product_id = [
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "203751",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "198999",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "199291",

  },

  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "256156",

  }
];
```

Second Array

```
var product_details = [
  {
    "id": "219",
    "product_id": "198999",
    "sku": "20148089",
    "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",

    "price": "39.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "220",
    "product_id": "199291",
    "sku": "20008307",
    "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",

    "price": "9.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "221",
    "product_id": "204759",
    "sku": "6009207908908",
    "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
    "price": "39.59"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "product_id": "199015",
    "sku": "6009182131643",
    "prod_name": "Bulk Gouda Cheese 900g",
    "price": "77.62"
  },
  {
    "id": "249",
    "product_id": "200051",
    "sku": "6009195203320",
    "prod_name": "Salted Butter 500g",
    "price": "76.95"
  }

]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: And what happen when it doesnt find the detail? is it not printed?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz: yes if it doest find nothing should be printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search every product_id and see if exists in the product_details, you can just do it with two nested for loops.

Example:

```
for(let i=0; i<product_id.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<product_details.length; j++){
      if(product_id[i].product_id === product_details[j].product_id){
        console.log(product_details[j]);
      }
    }
}
```

I hope I have the right idea. Good luck!!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search through product_id here is the solution which will return data in Object and if you want data in Array then use filter() instead of find().

```
var search = product_details.find(detail => {
    return detail.product_id === "199291";
});
```

**Your output will be**

```
{
     id: "220"
     price:"9.99"
     prod_name:"Medium Carrots 500g"
     product_id:"199291"
     sku:"20008307"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map each `product_id` and return the the first match in the `product_details` array

```
product_id.map(a=>({...a, ...product_details.find(b=>b.product_id == a.product_id)}))
```

You could also remove the ones that doest match adding `.filter(a=>a.id)`

```js
var product_id = [{
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "203751",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "198999",

  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "199291",

  },

  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "product_id": "256156",

  }
];

var product_details = [{
    "id": "219",
    "product_id": "198999",
    "sku": "20148089",
    "prod_name": "Chocolate Mousse 1L",

    "price": "39.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "220",
    "product_id": "199291",
    "sku": "20008307",
    "prod_name": "Medium Carrots 500g",

    "price": "9.99"
  },
  {
    "id": "221",
    "product_id": "204759",
    "sku": "6009207908908",
    "prod_name": "Fresh Spicy Lentil & Vegetable Soup 600g",
    "price": "39.59"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "product_id": "199015",
    "sku": "6009182131643",
    "prod_name": "Bulk Gouda Cheese 900g",
    "price": "77.62"
  },
  {
    "id": "249",
    "product_id": "200051",
    "sku": "6009195203320",
    "prod_name": "Salted Butter 500g",
    "price": "76.95"
  }

]

console.log(
  product_id.map(a=>({...a, ...product_details.find(b=>b.product_id == a.product_id)}))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but this how i always look for an item in an array.

```
function findInArray(productArray, productId){
for(product of productArray){
    if(product.productId === productId){
        return product;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly getting what you said. Maybe.. try this..

```js
product_id.forEach(prod => {
  if (prod) {
    product_details.forEach(detail => {
      if (detail && detail.product_id === prod.product_id) {
        console.log(detail)
      }
    })
  }
})
```